# How to execute multiple stored procedure queries from a file in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, callable-statement

I've used multiple sql queries to create stored procedures related to my project. Here is the sql file(consisting of multiple stored procedure queries), that i want to execute in java:

```
# -- USER-ADMIN ADD
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `users_admin_add` //
# -- remove above
CREATE PROCEDURE `users_admin_add`(
IN _author INT,
IN _name VARCHAR(100),
IN _mobile VARCHAR(20),
IN _email VARCHAR(100),
IN _address TEXT,
IN _username VARCHAR(30),
IN _password TEXT,
IN _pin INT,
IN _preferred VARCHAR(20),
IN _active BOOLEAN,
IN _fired BOOLEAN,
IN _access INT,
OUT _id INT
)
BEGIN
# -- declare
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT `id` FROM `users_admin` WHERE `id`=_author AND `active`=TRUE) THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid Author';
ELSEIF EXISTS (SELECT `id` FROM `users_admin` WHERE `username`=_username) THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Username Already exists';
ELSEIF EXISTS (SELECT `id` FROM `users_admin` WHERE `mobile`=_mobile) THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Mobile Already registered';
ELSE
# -- null checks
SET _active = IFNULL(_active,FALSE);
SET _fired = IFNULL(_fired,FALSE);
SET _preferred = IFNULL(_preferred,'PASSWORD');
SET _access = IFNULL(_access,(SELECT `level` FROM `core_access_types` WHERE `name`='RECEPTIONIST'));

# -- main
INSERT INTO `users_admin`(`name`, `mobile`, `email`, `address`, `username`, `password`, `pin`, `preferred`, `active`, `fired`, `access`, `author`) 
VALUES ( _name,  _mobile,  _email,  _address,  _username,  _password,  _pin,  _preferred,  _active,  _fired,  _access,  _author); 
SET _id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
SELECT * FROM `users_admin` WHERE `id`=_id;
END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;

# -- USER-ADMIN DELETE
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `users_admin_delete` //
# -- remove above
CREATE PROCEDURE `users_admin_delete`(
IN _author INT,
IN _user INT
)
BEGIN
# -- declare
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT `id` FROM `users_admin` WHERE `id`=_author AND `active`=TRUE) THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid Author';
ELSEIF EXISTS ( SELECT `id` FROM `users_admin` WHERE `fired`=TRUE AND `id`=_user) THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'This account has been disabled permanently';
ELSEIF NOT EXISTS (SELECT `id` FROM `users_admin` WHERE `id`=_user) THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid User';
ELSE
UPDATE `users_admin` SET `fired`=TRUE, `modified_at`=NOW(), `modifier`=_author WHERE `id`=_user;
SELECT * FROM `users_admin` WHERE `id`=_user;
END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I've used the methods like addBatch() and executeBatch() available in java, but they don't seem to work.
Here is my java code that i used last. i've tried many more methods,  i'd say, none of them worked:

```
private static DatabaseHandler handler = null;
String uname="root";
String pass="";
String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:17770/wdms_db?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;allowMultiQueries=true";
private static Statement stmnt=null;
private static Connection con=null;

static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) throws IOException 
{
  byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
  return new String(encoded, encoding);
}
private DatabaseHandler() throws SQLException {
    createsConnection();

    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        System.err.println("at procedures.sql---------------------------------------------------------------------");
        is = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\procedures.sql");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DatabaseHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    executeScript(con,is);
}
```

definition of executeScript(con, is):

```
static void executeScript(Connection conn, InputStream in)
    throws SQLException
{
//     System.out.println(in);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(in);
    s.useDelimiter("/\\*[\\s\\S]*?\\*/|--[^\\r\\n]*|;");

    Statement st = null;

    try
    {
    st = conn.createStatement();

    while (s.hasNext())
    {
        String line = s.next().trim();

        if (!line.isEmpty())
            System.out.println(line);
            st.execute(line);
    }
    // st.executeBatch();
    }
    finally
    {
    if (st != null)
        st.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide how you execute this from your code? if you are using CallableStatement you cannot do batch execution.

Comment: @dush, i've edited my question to provide more details.

Comment: you are executing incomplete sql statement from `st.execute(line)`. you have to extract single sql statements correclty from the the file and provide it into st.execute(line). ill post an example

Answer (score 0):

You are executing incomplete SQL statement from `st.execute(line)`.

If your SQL file looks like this:

```
---
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `users_admin_add`
---
CREATE PROCEDURE `users_admin_add`(
IN _author INT,
IN _name VARCHAR(100),
IN _mobile VARCHAR(20),
IN _email VARCHAR(100),
IN _address TEXT,
IN _username VARCHAR(30),
IN _password TEXT,
IN _pin INT,
IN _preferred VARCHAR(20),
IN _active BOOLEAN,
IN _fired BOOLEAN,
IN _access INT,
OUT _id INT
)
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT `id` FROM `users_admin` WHERE `id`=_author AND `active`=TRUE) THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid Author';
ELSEIF EXISTS (SELECT `id` FROM `users_admin` WHERE `username`=_username) THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Username Already exists';
ELSEIF EXISTS (SELECT `id` FROM `users_admin` WHERE `mobile`=_mobile) THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Mobile Already registered';
ELSE
SET _active = IFNULL(_active,FALSE);
SET _fired = IFNULL(_fired,FALSE);
SET _preferred = IFNULL(_preferred,'PASSWORD');
SET _access = IFNULL(_access,(SELECT `level` FROM `core_access_types` WHERE `name`='RECEPTIONIST'));

INSERT INTO `users_admin`(`name`, `mobile`, `email`, `address`, `username`, `password`, `pin`, `preferred`, `active`, `fired`, `access`, `author`) 
VALUES ( _name,  _mobile,  _email,  _address,  _username,  _password,  _pin,  _preferred,  _active,  _fired,  _access,  _author); 
SET _id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
SELECT * FROM `users_admin` WHERE `id`=_id;
END IF;
END
```

should use delimiter as follows

```
static void executeScript(Connection conn, InputStream in)
    throws SQLException
{
//     System.out.println(in);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(in);
    s.useDelimiter("---");

    Statement st = null;

    try
    {
    st = conn.createStatement();

    while (s.hasNext())
    {
        String line = s.next().trim();

        if (!line.isEmpty())
            System.out.println(line);
            st.execute(line);
    }
    // st.executeBatch();
    }
    finally
    {
    if (st != null)
        st.close();
    }
}
```

and you should close the Scanner also.

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException
it gives this error. @dush

Comment: you used my above mentioned sql file and change code to `s.useDelimiter("---")` right? I tested this in my local and works fine